# Como eu posso simplificar o acesso aos valores de interesse de um JSON em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, api

**Contexto:** estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que consome várias APIs. Os JSON retornados por essas APIs possuem a sua estrutura própria, onde muitas vezes não é das mais intuitivas para o programador poder explora-las.

**Exemplo:** suponha que eu esteja utilizando uma API externa, e que que este é JSON retornado de uma rota qualquer.

```
{
  "arvore": {
    "avo": {
      "pai": {
        "eu": "pedro"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Suponha também que a *única informação que me interessa* nesse JSON seja o valor da chave `eu`. Deste modo, todas as vezes que eu consumir esse recurso e obter esse JSON, terei que acessar minha informação de interesse assim: `obj['arvore']['avo']['pai']['eu']` ou assim `obj.arvore.avo.pai.eu`, etc.

**Problema/incômodo:** o acesso a essa informação de interesse é muito verboso. E isso pode inibir um pouco a rapidez do processo de desenvolvimento em um cenário maior, enfim.

---

Eu estava pensando em criar uma espécie de wrapper para os JSON retornados - dos recursos que eu mais consumo-. Por exemplo, ao invés de acessar a chave através da sua estrutura real (`obj['arvore']['avo']['pai']['eu']`), eu simplesmente poderia dar um `obj.eu` e então teria exatamente o mesmo resultado. Porém, antes de implementar isso, quis levantar essa discussão aqui. No mais, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Faz um mixin com um objeto seu que tenha métodos de acesso rápido. Mixin é a palavra chave.

Comment: Faltou a linguagem do contexto. Apesar que pelo formato da sua explanação está parecendo python, é isso? Se for bastaria um classe que lesse o json e disponibilizasse o que vc quizesse, no formato desejado, apesar de que eu não perderia tempo com isso, se não fosse o objetivo principal.

Comment: Conforme dito pelo colega @Sidon, seria bom deixar clara a linguagem em questão (se é JS mesmo, ou o quê). Creio que [edit] a questão para por a tag da linguagem desejada já é suficiente. Já adianto que o fato de ser verboso provavelmente não deveria ser um problema, visto que qualquer bom editor tem copy&paste e search/replace caso precise fazer uma alteração. Dependendo da linguagem bastaria algum #define, para simplificar a digitação ou centralizar o caminho em lugar específico. Ainda poderia criar alguma variável por referência, algo como `eu = &obj['arvore']['avo']['pai']['eu']`

Comment: Na verdade eu precisei disso em Python e em Javascript. Porém, pra ficar mais organizado, vou direcionar essa pergunta a Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução simples utilizando métodos [estáticos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#M%C3%A9todos_est%C3%A1ticos) do ECMAScript 6, tal como se segue no código. Neles, eu defino como retorno o caminho para a minha informação de interesse, simples assim.

```js
    var obj = {
        "arvore": {
            "avo": {
                "pai": {
                    "eu": "pedro"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Access {
        static getEu(obj) {
            return obj.arvore.avo.pai.eu;
        }
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = Access.getEu(obj);
```

Comment: Eu não recomendaria usar uma classe desse jeito somente para colocar um método estático nela, não faz muito sentido, se for assim, usar uma função era mais simples.

Comment: Então, eu utilizei as classes mais no sentido de criar grupos. Porque num contexto real, com dezenas de funções, as classes (ou grupos) ajudariam um pouco.

Comment: Caso esteja usando ES6, imports/exports já resolvem esse problema...

Answer (score 0):

É um bocado rebuscado, mas podes fazer uma função recursiva que procura as entries do objecto e se a primeira key do retorno for igual à key que tu estás à procura, então retorna esse valor - caso contrário chama a função outra vez com o *segundo* valor do retorno:

```
const tree = {
  "arvore": {
    "avo": {
      "pai": {
        "eu": {
          "nome": "pedro",
          "familia": "dev"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function getObjectValueByKey(key, _pool) {
  const pool = Object.entries(_pool);
  let found = null;

  pool[0].forEach(entry => {
    if (entry === key) {
      found = pool[0][1];
    }
  });

  if (found) return found;
  else return getObjectValueByKey(key, pool[0][1]);
}


const value = getObjectValueByKey('eu', tree);
console.log('value?', value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função que crie um alias para o seu objeto, apontando sempre para o path definido pela função.

```
function get(source, path) {
  return path.split('.').reduce((currentValue, propertyName) => {
    return currentValue && currentValue[propertyName]
  }, source);
}

function alias(source, aliasName, path) {
  return Object.defineProperty(source, aliasName, {
    get() {
      return get(this, path);
    }
  });
}

const obj = {
  "arvore": {
    "avo": {
      "pai": {
        "eu": "pedro"
      }
    }
  }
};

const decorated = alias(obj, 'eu', 'arvore.avo.pai.eu');

decorated.eu; // "pedro"

decorated.arvore.avo.pai.eu = "joão";

decorated.eu; // "joão"
```

Caso queira múltiplos aliases:

```
function aliases(source, aliases) {
  return aliases.reduce((decorated, args) => {
    return alias(decorated, ...args)
  }, source);
}

const decorated = aliases(obj, [
  ['avo', 'arvore.avo'],
  ['pai', 'avo.pai'],
  ['eu', 'pai.eu']
]);
```